# getPicklistValues function in LWC - Community without login

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, picklist, lightning-community

The Lightning Web Component(LWC) has few `<lighnting-combobox>` fields the values for those picklist values are retrieved via
`@Wire-getPicklistValues()` functionality.

Upon viewing the component in Lighting Community after login. getPicklistValues function returns the Picklist Values, when viewing without log-in values are not returned. ***( it's a support Portal- Case Object)***

JS

```
import AccessMethod_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.AccessMethod__c';

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: AccessMethod_FIELD
})
AccessMethodPicklistValues;
```

This is how am accessing

Update - @Wire-getPicklistValues didn't return the piclistvalues.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would be an access level case. Make sure you have set the permissions correctly.

If thys community should be visible to anyone without login - consider creating guest user profile with proper permissions.